# SQLServer: LAG & LEAD instead of recursive calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, window-functions

I am pretty new to the new version of SQL Server 2016 and haven't used the new LAG & LEAD functions yet.

If i understood right, it will make work easier in cases where we currently use the ROW_NUMBER() function and furthermore join the results to connect the records in a certain order.

A case where i currently use this way to connect the records is:

```
;WITH IncrementingRowNums AS
(
    SELECT d.MyKey
          ,d.Outstanding
          ,d.Rate
          ,AMO.PaymentAmount
          ,AMO.AmoDate
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.MyKey ORDER BY AMO.AmoDate ASC) AS RowNum
      FROM Deals d
     INNER JOIN Amortization AMO
        ON d.MyKey = AMO.MyKey
),   
lagged AS
(
    SELECT MyKey 
          ,Outstanding AS new_outstanding
          ,Rate
          ,PaymentAmount
          ,AmoDate
          ,RowNum
      FROM IncrementingRowNums
     WHERE RowNum = 1
  UNION ALL
    SELECT i.MyKey
          ,(l.new_outstanding - l.PaymentAmount) 
            * (1 + i.Rate * (DATEDIFF(DAY,l.AmoDate, i.AmoDate)/365.25))    
             AS new_outstanding
          ,i.Rate
          ,i.PaymentAmount
          ,i.AmoDate
          ,i.RowNum
      FROM IncrementingRowNums i
     INNER JOIN lagged l
        ON i.RowNum = l.RowNum + 1
       AND i.MyKey = l.MyKey
```

Whats the best way to solve this solution with the LAG&LEAD functions?
I tried several ways, but it never worked out.

The only thing i want to calculate is the column new_outstanding. 
Which calculates like:

```
(previous_record.new_outstanding  - previous_record.PaymentAmount)
* (1 + current_record.Rate * (DATEDIFF(DAY,previous_record.AmoDate, current_record.AmoDate)/365.25))
```

As there is no SQL Server 2016 Version on rextester, i can just provide a little test-data and the my old solution of the recursive calculation: http://rextester.com/WVTM46505 
Thanks

Comment: Lag and Lead was introduced in 2012, so it's supported on rextester. Also, They are not recursive. They can only get you the value of a different row as an extra column in the current row.

Comment: @ZoharPeled thanks for the information. it seems i never paid attention to those functions before

Comment: so there is no way to solve the topic without recursion?

Comment: If you need the calculation to spread over more than 2 rows I don't think it can be solved without a recursive query. However, someone else might have a solution for you.

Comment: Are you sure about your logic? Don't you have to restart the calculation for each MyKey, i.e. `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.MyKey ORDER BY AMO.AmoDate ASC)`

Comment: @dnoeth thanks - seems like it happened when i simplified the statement before posting here - i just updated the SQL in the question

Comment: `LAG` and `LEAD` don't help you here. Your recursive query is the perfect solution for the given problem, as you must build the value iteratively (i.e. there is no math formula to get the value from only the current and previous row).

Comment: Not even a cummulative sum `SUM(..) over (...)` can help with this one.  Perhaps looping through a cursor would be another method, but that's hardly a simplification compared to the recursive CTE method.